# Commons-dpcp jar & javax.servlet-api issue

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons-dbcp

I am new to spring and learning spring MVC by doing some samples. I am getting jar issues in `commons-dpcp` and `javax.servlet-api` jar issues which is not loaded properly.I tried downloading from different sites but still am getting errors. Please some one help me to fix this issue.

```
Error creating bean with name 'contactsDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies 
failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory 
com.spring.hib.dao.ContactsDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class 
[org.apache.commons.dpcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in 
ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dpcp.BasicDataSource
```

Comment: which version of commons-dbcp jar ur using and spring jars too ??

Comment: I have found one thing that commons-dpcp 1.4 jar works only for jdk1.6 and under. So I am checking for other alternatives.

Comment: Hi Naren, I have used commons-dpcp 1.4 jar.